# Mount USB to the same directory Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, mount, usb-drive

I have a USB key which is mounted to a directory that I have created. For this I have edited fstab file in Ubuntu The problem is that if I disconnect this key(which was in /dev/sdb) and connect another USB key, this one is not mounted at the same point.(because it is in /dev/sdb2) How can I make that only on, once a connected USB key is mounted at the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses /media as default place for automount, so you can just use a hack for your problem.

```
sudo ln -s /media /path-to-your-dir
```

Now whatever the usb is mounted then it will be listed in some dir inside your dir stated above.

This is some hack, maybe you can find better answer.

Comment: Yes, but if I have 3 different USBs and I connect and disconnect each one of them is it possible that they are mounted in the same folder?

Comment: No. The problem is that I have a Java app who is lloking into a directory to do an update. This directory has to be the mounting point for the USB. But each time I have another USB, it is not mounted in this directory. FOr one USB I can edit fstab, but if it is another USB it is not recognized

Comment: I didn't understand /dev/sdd1 it is all the time /dev/sdd1 or is only in my case; for me the first time is /dev/sdb

Comment: Each time another name : once the first connected is /dev/sdb; if I change the usb for exaple the second day I come with another one, it will be /dev/sdb1 or /dev/dsdc

Comment: check update now

Comment: Yes, there are all media directories, but I should seen only what I have on my USB key in /path-to-dir